# how to capture a certain http code responce with tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

I want to capture http errors on openwrt.
ngrep utility would be very useful but is not available there also tshark is not available also.
so it leaves me with tcpdump.

how do I tell tcpdump to capture just the connection that resulted in a http code error? in this case 403 forbidden.

Comment: Did you manage to get any message which flows through the router from a client to a server? Is that possible?